# Java - How to make a Mac popover window?

Tags: java, user-interface

How can you make a popover window with Java on Mac? I can't find the answer anywhere on the internet.
(Like this)
[image]

Thanks!

Edit: Yes, I mean the pull down type, called "sheets" by Apple

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the "pull down" style pop up, there's nothing in Java that would allow you to do this in a simple API call. You can fake it using a JPanel on at the windows glass pane. If you don't care about the pull down style, the you can simply use a modal dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Swing then the `JDialog` is probably what you seek. See the Java Tutorial [How to make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

A `JDialog` is linked to a parent container, such as a `JFrame`. If the container is closed then the `JDialog` closes; if the frame is minimized then the `JDialog` is minimized.